Troubleshooting uploading symbols to Crashlytics
I'm trying to upload Crashlytics symbols to Firebase for an Android app that is being minimized with R8. The reported crashes are not being de-obfuscated. There are no errors when building or when running the command ./gradlew app:uploadCrashlyticSymbolFile* where * is the build variant.

Is there a clear cut way to see the uploaded symbols using the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard?
Are there logs recording the uploading of symbols and the status of the upload?

I've followed a few articles but those articles do not provide any means of debugging the uploading process.
Configuring build.gradle, using the command ./gradlew app:uploadCrashlyticSymbolFile*, adding rules to the proguard files, ...
The command firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload ... fails with
java.io.IOException: Breakpad symbol generation failed (exit=1), see STDERR


Symbols are related to native code (c++) For R8 you will need to run ./gradlew uploadCrashlyticsMappingFile

I ended creating a new project purely for troubleshooting upload of Crashlytics mapping files. I was able to get it working by specifying mappingFileUploadEnabled = true under android > buildTypes > release build type > configure<CrashlyticsExtension> of the app build.gradle
